# Architecture for a modular p2p web application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, real-time, p2p

I'm working on a final project for a computer science degree that includes building a web application that aims to connect 2 users and provide various collaborative tools.

I'm building with node, express, angular and mongodb but if there is a more suitable architecture tell me!

So far, the base page has been set up with audio, video and text chat using webRTC so there is a persistent data connection between the two peers.

One of the users will act as a tutor and should be able to insert a 'block' of content. There will be a number of different blocks available such as a reading block or whiteboard block. Each block will provide different tools. In the reading block, a user can select a word to be highlighted and the connected peer will see the highlighted word. In the whiteboard block the user can draw something and again it is seen by the peer.

These blocks are very modular by nature and I want to make it as extendable as possible. Is Angular the best way to go for providing the functionality on the front end? An initial implementation is using the webRTC data connection to send a specific code to the peer which invokes a method on their side. This works great for inserting the blocks but I imagine it will quickly become cumbersome as more blocks are added with various tools all needing to send data between each other.

Some mock ups...

View from the students perspective[image: Student View]

View from the tutors perspective[image: Tutor View]

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is quite broad, there is no concrete answer. Angular and other frameworks with similar features are great building blocks for complex applications. The same could be said w/the other parts of your stack, they are perfectly suitable for what you're doing and there are plenty of other suitable alternatives. Keep asking yourself these types of questions as you build the app, often it's not the framework but how you use the framework that can make things cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks Sunil. I realize it is a broad question but I guess I'm looking for some confirmation that the approach is viable and doesn't have anything too seriously wrong with it.

Comment: It sounds perfectly viable to me! By making things as modular as possible, you'll have a good foundation to build on -- granted, that's easier said than done :)

Comment: Did you finish this project?